# How to select last element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I want to select the  last `audio` element on my webpage http://sycoscientistrecords.github.io/ I tried:

```
$(" audio:last-of-type");
```

The problem is that it returns all the `audio` elements:

`Object { length: 12, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → index.html, selector: " audio:last-of-type", 12 more… }`

There are 12 audio elements on the page and the jquery selector returns all of them.

So, How do I select last element with jquery?

Comment: did you try $(" audio:last")

Comment: `$('audio:last')` or `$('audio').last()`.

Comment: The :last-of-type selector matches elements that have no other element with the same parent and the same element name coming after it in the document tree. . Where as last is independent of that ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/). You could use the `:last` selector too, but then it can't be passed directly to the browser's selector engine.

```
$("audio").last()
```

---

> Why doesn't `last-of-type` work?

The [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/) for the selector says:

> Selects all elements that are the last among siblings of the same element name.

So in your case it would be matching all the last `audio` elements that were inside of other elements.

Comment: `last-of-type` selects elements in each parent elements. so if you have 12 parents and 12 children then that would return you 12 objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have a check in your site. If you use `$(" audio").last()`, it will return array of last element.

Use: `$(" audio").last()[0]` to get the last element.